# prevent update a specific attribute

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a document table with the columns id, collection, shelfmark, sort_order.

By updating a document the sort_order is set to 0 even though there is no sort_order input field in the form.

I tried with

```
 unset($aData['sort_order']);
```

as last statement in the form but after submitting the sort_order attribute is set to 0.

My Form - Snippet:

```
   <form class="form" id="edit-form" method="POST" action="cms/documents/update/<?= $sDocumentId ?>">
     <tr>
          <td><?= form_label('Display Shelfmark:&nbsp;*', 'shelfmark') ?></td>
          <td><?php $aAttributes = array('name'          => 'shelfmark',
                                         'id'            => 'shelfmark',
                                         'value'         => set_value('shelfmark', '', FALSE),
                                         'placeholder'   => 'Example: Cod. Sang. 70'
                                         );
                      $sError = '';
                      if (form_error('shelfmark') != '') {
                        $aAttributes['class'] = 'm form-error';
                        $sError = '<span class="help-inline help-error">' . form_error('shelfmark') . '</span>';
                      }
                      echo form_input($aAttributes) . $sError;
               ?>
            </td>
        </tr>

  <div id="saveButtons">
    <a href="cms/documents/cancelUpdate/<?= $sDocumentId ?>" class="btn">Cancel</a>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="save-document"><i class="icon-ok-sign icon-white"></i> Save &amp; Finish</button>
    <a href="#" id="save-and-continue" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i> Save &amp; Continue Editing</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

How can I prevent to update the sort_order attribute in the database table?

--- Update 2:

In my Documents Model:

```
  public function updateDocument($sDocumentId, $aDocumentData) {
    $this->filterDataArray('documents_revisions', $aDocumentData);
    // before updating, check if latest revision has identical content (except updated_at and user id)
    if ($this->Revisions_model->revisionIsIdentical($aDocumentData, $this->Revisions_model->getLatestRevision($sDocumentId))) {
      return true;
    }
    $aDocumentData['document_id'] = $sDocumentId;
    $aDocumentData['updated_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $aDocumentData['ion_auth_user_id'] = $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->id;
    return $this->Revisions_model->createRevision($aDocumentData);
  }
```

And in my Revisions Model:

```
public function createRevision($aRecordToSave) {
    // get latest revision for the record we are trying to save (there should always be at least one revision, except when adding a new record)
    $oLatestRevision = $this->getLatestRevision($aRecordToSave[$this->sForeignKey]);
    // check if the latest revision is identical to the one we are trying to save - only save if they're not identical
    if ($this->revisionIsIdentical($aRecordToSave, $oLatestRevision)) {
      return true; // don't create a revision if the same record data already exists in revisions table
    }
    else { // latest revision is not identical to the record we are trying to save
      // start a database transaction
      $this->db->trans_begin();

      $this->db->where($this->sForeignKey, $aRecordToSave[$this->sForeignKey]);
      $this->db->update($this->sRevisionsTable, array('latest' => 0));

      // check if there are already <maxNumberOfRevisions> and overwrite oldest revision if necessary
      $aRecordToSave['latest'] = 1;
      if ($this->maxNumberOfRevisionsReached($aRecordToSave[$this->sForeignKey])) { // using foreignKey because record ID is unset already
        $this->db->where('updated_at', $this->getOldestRevisionTime($aRecordToSave[$this->sForeignKey]));
        $this->db->where($this->sForeignKey, $aRecordToSave[$this->sForeignKey]);
        $this->db->update($this->sRevisionsTable, $aRecordToSave);
      }
      else { // insert a new revision
        $this->db->insert($this->sRevisionsTable, $aRecordToSave);
      }

      if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
        return false;
      }
      else {
        $this->db->trans_commit();
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
```

Is there a CodeIgniter way to exclude 'sort_order' from $aRecordToSave ?

Comment: Please post the SQL query you're running.

Comment: @Twinfriends, updated with my form snippet.

Comment: That's 861 lines of code sir.

Comment: you need to post your model code for this method - $this->Model->updateDocument($sDocumentId, $_POST));

Comment: @TigerTiger yeah, I updated my Post.

Comment: You will need to post your createRevision() method too.

Comment: @TigerTiger ok, done.

Comment: I think what's happening here is that as you are not passing sort_order value in your post data, your revisions model or your database is setting up a default value for this field.

Comment: Yes, do you know how to prevent this? Could you provide this as an answer so that I can mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to TigerTiger's comment I solved this issue with setting the sort_order to that from the latest revision:

```
$aRecordToSave['sort_order'] = $oLatestRevision->sort_order;
```